# Group array of objects by their array property elements

Tags: ruby

I have this array of cities:

```
Bakersfield, California
Interstates: ["I-5"]

Oakland, California
Interstates: ["I-80"]

Atlanta, Georgia
Interstates: ["I-20", "I-75", "I-86"]

Cleveland, Ohio
Interstates: ["I-71", "I-77", "I-80", "I-90"]

Arlington, Texas
Interstates: ["I-20", "I-30"]
```

The name, the state and the interstates array are properties of each city.

I want to group them by their interstates so the final result would look something like this:

```
I-20: [Arlington, Atlanta]
I-5: [Bakersfield]
I-86: [Atlanta]
...
```

Is there a quick way to do this?

EDIT: Here is the true array, just as @wurde example.

```
cities = {
  'Bakersfield' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-5']
  },
  'Oakland' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-80']
  },
  'Atlanta' => {
    state: 'Georgia',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-75", "I-86"]
  },
  'Cleveland' => {
    state: 'Ohio',
    interstate: ["I-71", "I-77", "I-80", "I-90"]
  },
  'Arlington' => {
    state: 'Texas',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-30"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the true Array? Is this an Array of Hashes or is it a multi dimensional Array? With True data it will be easier to determine a functional efficient solution to the problem.

Comment: ...and while you're at it, please assign it to a variable (e.g., `cities = [ {city: "Bakersfield", state: "California", Interstates: ["I-5"] }, ... ]`, so readers can refer to `cities` without having to define it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mapping = {}

cities.each do |city|
    city.interstates.each do |interstate|
      mapping[interstate] ||= []
      mapping[interstate] << city
    end
end
```

Comment: consider `(mapping[interstate] ||= []) << city`. Looks weird first, but once you got the hang of it it becomes useful in probably many places.

Comment: @Felix In that case why not consider `mapping = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}` Then it would just be `mapping[interstate] << city`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, thats another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Given the assumption that @wurde's Hash structure is true I would do something like this

```
cities = {
  'Bakersfield' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-5']
  },
  'Oakland' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-80']
  },
  'Atlanta' => {
    state: 'Georgia',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-75", "I-86"]
  },
  'Cleveland' => {
    state: 'Ohio',
    interstate: ["I-71", "I-77", "I-80", "I-90"]
  },
  'Arlington' => {
    state: 'Texas',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-30"]
  }
}


cities.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |(city_name,data),h|
  data[:interstate].each do |interstate|
    h[interstate] << "#{city_name}, #{data[:state]}"
  end
end
#=> {"I-5"=>["Bakersfield, California"], 
     "I-80"=>["Oakland, California", "Cleveland, Ohio"], 
     "I-20"=>["Atlanta, Georgia", "Arlington, Texas"], 
     "I-75"=>["Atlanta, Georgia"], 
     "I-86"=>["Atlanta, Georgia"], 
     "I-71"=>["Cleveland, Ohio"], 
     "I-77"=>["Cleveland, Ohio"], 
     "I-90"=>["Cleveland, Ohio"], 
     "I-30"=>["Arlington, Texas"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cities = {
  'Bakersfield' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-5']
  },
  'Oakland' => {
    state: 'California',
    interstate: ['I-80']
  },
  'Atlanta' => {
    state: 'Georgia',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-75", "I-86"]
  },
  'Cleveland' => {
    state: 'Ohio',
    interstate: ["I-71", "I-77", "I-80", "I-90"]
  },
  'Arlington' => {
    state: 'Texas',
    interstate: ["I-20", "I-30"]
  }
}

interstates = {}
cities.each do |city|
  city[1][:interstate].each do |road|
    interstates[road] ||= []
    interstates[road] << city[0]
  end
end

puts interstates.inspect
#=> {
#=>   "I-5"=>["Bakersfield"],
#=>   "I-80"=>["Oakland", "Cleveland"],
#=>   "I-20"=>["Atlanta", "Arlington"],
#=>   "I-75"=>["Atlanta"],
#=>   "I-86"=>["Atlanta"],
#=>   "I-71"=>["Cleveland"],
#=>   "I-77"=>["Cleveland"],
#=>   "I-90"=>["Cleveland"],
#=>   "I-30"=>["Arlington"]
#=> }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have:

```
cities = {
  'Bakersfield' => ['I-5'],
  'Oakland' => ['I-80'],
  'Atlanta' => ["I-20", "I-75", "I-86"],
  'Cleveland' => ["I-71", "I-77", "I-80", "I-90"],
  'Arlington' => ["I-20", "I-30"]
}
```

**Longer version** We can get what you want by this operations:

```
require 'set'
interstates = cities.inject(Set.new){|all,item| all+item[1]} # => #<Set: {"I-5", "I-80", "I-20", "I-75", "I-86", "I-71", "I-77", "I-90", "I-30"}>
result = interstates.map{|inter| [inter, cities.select{|_,interstates| interstates.include?(inter)}.keys]}.to_h # => {"I-5"=>["Bakersfield"], "I-80"=>["Oakland", "Cleveland"], "I-20"=>["Atlanta", "Arlington"], "I-75"=>["Atlanta"], "I-86"=>["Atlanta"], "I-71"=>["Cleveland"], "I-77"=>["Cleveland"], "I-90"=>["Cleveland"], "I-30"=>["Arlington"]}
```

We use `Set` because it's efficient in given settings (for more elegant syntax, see note below). On line 2 we get all `interstates` using `Enumerable`'s `inject` method. Final result is obtained on line 3, where we use mapping and filtering (`map` and `select` methods). Note, that `to_h` method is available from Ruby 2.1. If you are on older Ruby, you can convert mapped array to `Hash` using `Hash[array]`.

**One-liner** It can even be written as one-liner:

```
cities.inject(Set.new){|all,item| all+item[1]}.map{|inter| [inter, cities.select{|_,interstates| interstates.include?(inter)}.keys]}.to_h
```

**Note** I included `Set` here for performance. If you prefer readability, then it's much shorter simply write `interstates = cities.values.flatten.uniq`, as @engineersmnky noted in comment.

Comment: why not `interstates = cities.values.flatten`? I don't see a need to inject a `Set`

Comment: Is it good in terms of performance? I have feeling `Set` should perform it much faster. Your version is much shorter though.

Comment: @engineersmnky btw, the full version is `interstates = cities.values.flatten.uniq`

Answer (score 0):

Using @wurde's example (thank you, thank you, thank you):

```
cities.each_with_object({}) do |(k,g),h|
  g[:interstate].each { |i| h.update(i=>[k]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
end
  #=> {"I-5" =>["Bakersfield"],
  #    "I-80"=>["Oakland", "Cleveland"],
  #    "I-20"=>["Atlanta", "Arlington"],
  #    "I-75"=>["Atlanta"],
  #    "I-86"=>["Atlanta"],
  #    "I-71"=>["Cleveland"],
  #    "I-77"=>["Cleveland"],
  #    "I-90"=>["Cleveland"],
  #    "I-30"=>["Arlington"]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses the block:

```
{ |_,o,n| o+n }
```

to determine values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. The key is the intestate (written `_` because it is not be used), `o` is an array of cities for the key in the hash `h` being constructed and `n` is an array of a single city for the merging hash `{ i=>[k] }`.